# SQL Insert one column into another table where there is a match

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables a and b.

a:

```
TYPE            nvarchar(MAX)   
USERID          nvarchar(MAX)   
FIRSTNAME       nvarchar(MAX)   
LASTNAME        nvarchar(MAX)   
USERSTATUS      nvarchar(MAX)   
EMPLOYEETYPE    nvarchar(MAX)   
MANAGERID       nvarchar(MAX)   
STATUS          nvarchar(MAX)   
WEEKNUM         nvarchar(MAX)   
POLICYNAME      nvarchar(MAX)   
Acc_Check       nvarchar(MAX)
```

b:

```
TYPE            nvarchar(MAX)   
USERID          nvarchar(MAX)   
FIRSTNAME       nvarchar(MAX)   
LASTNAME        nvarchar(MAX)   
USERSTATUS      nvarchar(MAX)   
EMPLOYEETYPE    nvarchar(MAX)   
MANAGERID       nvarchar(MAX)   
STATUS          nvarchar(MAX)   
WEEKNUM         nvarchar(MAX)   
Acc_Check       nvarchar(MAX)   
Policy_Name     nvarchar(MAX)
```

Table b is created by using SELECT DISTINCT on table a without POLICYNAME.

I now need to add the correct policyname back in to the new table.

Where Acc_Check is equal in both tables I want to take the matching value of a.POLICYNAME and insert it into b.Policy_Name

Comment: Please provide what query you got so far.

Comment: What happens when there is more than one match in table a for a given check in table b?  Sample data and desired results would help (you can simplify the sample data so it doesn't have quite so many columns).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to join these tables

```
UPDATE b
SET b.Policy_Name  = a.POLICYNAME      
FROM b INNER JOIN a
ON b.Acc_Check = a.Acc_Check
```